# change Image assets depend on state changed with cubit (flutter)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-cubit

I have 2 ImageAssets in my flutter project I want to switch between them depending on action,
I am using cubit and states.
the image changes after going to another widget and then coming back
how can I refresh the widget or do this without a stateful widget

this is my image and I want to switch between the grey one and basic one

```
indicator:Image.asset(cubit.planeState ? ImageAssets.plane : ImageAssets.planeGrey )),
```

and this the OnButtonPressed

```
 btnOkOnPress: () {
                          context.read<RehlatechCubit>().onPlaneStateChanged();
                        },
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have set up the page with cubit.

1. Modify the state (not the cubit) from a method
2. Emit the new state
3. Ensure the widget is wrapped in a BlocBuilder/BlocSelector/BlocConsumer

Psuedo Code

```
// rehlatech_cubit.dart

onPlaneStateChanged() {
 ...
 /// Mutate the current state with the plane state
 /// Make a copy or create a new state all together
 emit(state.copyWith(planeState: true));
}
```

Ensure that your widget to be updated is wrapped in a BlocBuilder

```
// widget.dart

Scaffold(
  body: BlocBuilder< RehlatechCubit, RehlatechState>(
   builder: (context, state) {
     // The state that is to be changed
     return Content(
      ...
      child: WidgetToBeUpdated(
          indicator:Image.asset(state.planeState ? 
            ImageAssets.plane : ImageAssets.planeGrey,
       ),
      ),
     )
    )
   }
  )
 );
```